# Assign a "shortcut" for a module id in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I'm using [Bower](http://bower.io/) to manage dependencies for the client. Each javaScript file is in its own folder:

```
bower_components
|-- backbone
    |-- backbone.js
|-- jquery
    |-- jquery.js
|-- backbone.syphon
    | -- lib
         |-- amd
             |-- backbone.syphon.js
```

Every time I need to define a view, I need to specify specify the full path to `backbone.syphon.js`:

```
define(['backbone.syphon/lib/amd/backbone.syphon', 'backbone'],
    function (BackboneSymphon, Backbone) {
        // View code
    }
);
```

Is there a way to define a "shortcut" (like shimming for Backbone) to a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can define it in `paths` [config setting](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config)

```
var require = {
  paths: {
    'backbone.syphon': 'backbone.syphon/lib/amd/backbone.syphon'
  }
}
```